# Is it possible to have a species where everyone is both male and female?

Tags: humanoid, reproduction, sex

I'm trying to create a humanoid species where all members can both impregnate each other and carry children. Each member would be sort of interchangeably male and female, in the sense that they could preform the function of both sexes. Is this scientifically possible? Are there any known species that work this way?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151677/discussion-on-question-by-j-rubio-is-it-possible-to-have-a-species-where-everyo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even among hermaphrodite species, competition over mates is unavoidable. There are two types of hermaphroditism:

1: Alternating male/female cycle: As the example of clownfish, the dominant fish becomes the male. This allows the father to fertilize as many "females" as possible, and has the greatest number of offsprings. When a male loses a fight to another fish, the loser becomes female. This is not exactly "true hermaphroditism" as being both male and female at the same time, but that says that no fish is innately born as either male or female.

2: Who "rapes" the other - The flatworms in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn3xluIRh1Y) are an example of competing over who "stabs" the other with its penis. The fight may last an hour. The winner impregnates more mates than what the loser did. It may be possible that the two eventually stab each other, but the stronger one is more likely to repeat it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible, it already happens in real life.

If I remember correctly, snails are an example of creature with such feature: when they mate, the male half fertilise the female half of the mating companion.

Another species has a much weirder behaviour: the two males fight by "fencing" with their penises: the first one to be pierced becomes the female and gets fertilised.